# Find google sheet id from sheet name using nodejs and Google Sheets API v4

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets-api

I would like to find a google sheet id (as in the .../edit#gid="SHEET_ID" query parameter) from the sheet name using nodejs and the Google Sheets v4 API. If I understand correctly the following code should work, but the response does not contain any "sheetIds" at all. Any idea what I've maybe missed?

```
const request = {
    spreadsheetId: GS_ID,
    ranges: [sheetName],
    includeGridData: false
};
let res = await GS.spreadsheets.get(request);

console.log(res.data.properties.sheetId);
```

I only get this data, so the sheets properties seem to be missing

```
{ spreadsheetId: '###',
  properties:
   { title: '###',
     locale: 'en_US',
     autoRecalc: 'ON_CHANGE',
     timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo',
     defaultFormat: {...},
  sheets: [ { properties: [Object] } ],
  spreadsheetUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit' }
```

Comment: Hi Jacob, does something like res.data.getSheets() return an array that can be filtered?

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

The `ranges` parameter needs to be in A1 notation to retrieve sheet information from the response. To retrieve sheet information, iterate through the sheets array and get the sheetID from a particular sheet name:

**Sample:**

```
const rangeName = 'A1:B1';
const sheetName = 'Sheet1';
const GS_ID = <insert spreadsheet ID here>;
const request = {
    spreadsheetId: GS_ID,
    ranges: rangeName,
    includeGridData: false
};
let res = await GS.spreadsheets.get(request);

for (i = 0; i < res.sheets.length; i++) {
  if (res.sheets[i].title === sheetName) {
    console.log(res.sheets[i].sheetId); // get sheet ID here
  }
}
```

**References:**

[Sheets API | Spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get#query-parameters)

[Object Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet)

[Object Sheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#SheetProperties)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation, oddly enough I still only get an empty sheets object in the response "sheets: [ [Object] ]"